# How to approach for creation of below Custom View?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, customization, nsparagraphstyle

I have a view as below. Which have dynamic image whose height can vary and the text on right side of image and below the image. Both text should come as paragraph as we see in textbook. So what is best approach to achieve this. Is it possible to have both paragraph in implementing with one `UILabel`?
[image]

Comment: why not using `UITextView` for the paragraphs and let Autolayout do the work

Comment: I must use one UITextView. how would it possible to rendered text in continued below Image and right hand side?

Comment: What about using a `UIWebView` because it looks like `float` effect in `CSS`

Comment: No,can't use webview, this question asked me in interview so wondering the answer around that question.